# Re naming multiple PC' and then Joining a Domain from a CSV File

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, hostname

I need to be able to re name and then join a domain, multiple PC's from a CSV file.

Content of CSV is for example :-

```
oldpcname1,newpcname1
oldpcname2,newpcname2
```

etc..

The code is as follows :-

```
$File = "C:\computer_names.csv"
$domain = "MBTEST.LOCAL"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\Administrator"
$user2 = "administrator"
$pass2 = "pa55w0rd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$lcred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($user2, $pass2)
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
 
 
$computerList= Import-Csv -Path $File `
                          -Delimiter "," `
                          -Header OldName,NewName
 
foreach ($Computer in $computerList)
{
Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -NewName $Computer.NewName -LocalCredential $lcred 
Add-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -Domain 'MBTEST.local' -Domaincredential $credential -LocalCredential $lcred -Restart 
Start-Sleep -seconds 5 
}
```

Problem I am having is access denied & WMI error's, the script seems to try and do what it is supposed to but is getting blocked. I am running from the DC with full blown admin rights, no firewalls on, can browse the C$ of the test VMS (1 DC & 2 Workstations in test env.)

```
Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'bongo4' with the following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
At C:\SHARED\Batch_Rename_PC_and_Join.ps1:20 char:1
+ Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -NewName $Computer.Ne ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (bongo4:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
 
Add-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'bongo4' with the following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
At C:\SHARED\Batch_Rename_PC_and_Join.ps1:21 char:1
+ Add-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -Domain 'ICTMBTST.local' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (bongo4:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
 
Rename-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'bongo3' with the following error message: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).
At C:\SHARED\Batch_Rename_PC_and_Join.ps1:20 char:1
+ Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -NewName $Computer.Ne ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (bongo3:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
 
Add-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'bongo3' with the following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
At C:\SHARED\Batch_Rename_PC_and_Join.ps1:21 char:1
+ Add-Computer -ComputerName $Computer.OldName -Domain 'ICTMBTST.local' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (bongo3:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

Comment: Seems like your header line is somehow read as data row as well

Comment: Is the header  "Oldname, Newname"  stored in the frist line of the CSV file?  If so, you should remove the -header clause from your Import-Csv.

Comment: It looks like the Add-Computer is not being done once for each computer.  The foreach loop should have one set of braces that span both the Rename-Computer and the Add-Computer cmdlets.

Comment: Do you need a -restart clause on the Rename-Computer cmdlet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, I have put the rename-comp* and add-computer lines, in one set of parenthesis, taken column heading names out of csv, and am a tad closer I think. Not sure if I need restart clause, but most research seems to have it in the examples. I'll edit the OP to show you where I'm at now...thanks

Comment: in the latest batch of error I changed the name of the PC's in the CSV. The test machines are called bongo3,4 etc..

Comment: Think there is some limitation to this method if I ran it on the PC itself it works, the minute it goes across to a remote PC - access denied again...